# HighStock shows data not presents at specific interval using gap size?

Tags: highcharts

Hi I used highstock to for irregular time and I used gap size for showing gap in graph if data not presents. 
More  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yogesh_0586/x68casgx/12/) here I shows message in `info div` now I want to shows this message dynamically according to last time gap in chart so my expected output should be as below

[image]

Here I want to shows last missing interval data dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something like this:

```
$('#container').highcharts().series[0].xData.forEach(function (t) {
    if((t - previous) < min)
    {
        min = t - previous;
    }
    else if((t - previous) > min * gap)
    {
        x1 = previous;
        x2 = t;                        
    }
    previous = t;
});
```

and I manually got the gap with checking every `x` value. Here's the fiddle with working code: http://jsfiddle.net/x68casgx/13/